# Flutter save data on device from firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to understand how to optimize the use of accesses to the Firebase database.
I have a database containing: mountain refuges and routes.

Practically every opening of the application all the necessary data are downloaded from the database.

My idea would be to save the relevant data in a json file, and only when the user wants more information on this data does the read access to the database take place.

[image: Idea]

How can I reduce read access to the database? Is it possible to save the most "relevant" data in a json file on the device so as not to download the "relevant" data every time the user opens the app?

Comment: Firebase itself maintains a local database. So when you have no internet it still works.

Comment: If you still want to you can create your own cache mechanism by only getting data from the firestore when there is nothing in the sqlite database and then use it when needed

Comment: It's not for internet connection problem. I want to reduce the useless operations of lecture. Which are limited in firebase free version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about pricing, Firestore is billed by interactions with the database [reads, writes, deletes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#pricing_overview), not quantity of data (ignoring Stored Data for this use case)

Additionally, Queries are shallow: they only return documents in a particular collection or collection group and do not return subcollection data.

So as long as your structure supports it, showing the higher level List of Places should be the only reads you're doing until the user actually selects a place to get more details on.

If you have a million places, leverage pagination to only load enough to support the UI - say 100 at a time. That will limit the number of reads needed as well.